# How to make app constants or env config fetched from the server to be available in all Redux reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the application I'm working on, we fetch the app constants and env configs from the server. How can these values be accessed across all the reducers?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: We have global app constants that is fetched from the server and saved as part of the redux state. I would like to use this state in other reducers while performing CRUD operations. Hope it's a bit more clear.

Comment: If you already have this information at state, you can use it in every async action right? If you are using redux-thunk, it accepts few arguments (dispatch, getState), you can extract those saved options from getState() and  pass it to API call (or some abstraction). Other idea that might work is https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html but as you can read its not good approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a thinking but you can make a higher order reducer who wrap this env config and your app constants. Take a look [here](http://slides.com/omnidan/hor).

Comment: Ah looks interesting. I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually template the env vars into the main html body inside a script tag inside an object called __env. I then import them through a window.__env in my js files.